# Are Dotnet Testcontainers broken om M1 macs?

Tags: c#, docker, apple-m1, testcontainers

I am trying to make Testcontainers for .Net run on my M1 mac (2021 Macbook Pro - Ventura 13.4).

To simplify the problem, I am first trying to run the [Testcontainers for .Net Hello World example](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/).

I created a new console app using `dotnet new console --name HelloTestcontainers` and added Testcontainers with `dotnet add package Testcontainers -v 3.2.0` (since omitting version as per the example threw an error)

I pasted the example code and added `using` statements to compile. See `program.cs` listing below.

The program throws on `await container.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` with

```
Unhandled exception. Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"invalid mount config for type \"bind\": stat /host_mnt/Users/me/.docker/run/docker.sock: operation not supported"}
```

I am using Docker Desktop 4.19.0, Engine 23.0.5. I get the same result regardless of whether or not Docker is configured to "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation".

Is there a bug with M1 macs and Testcontainers (for .Net)?

Are there any workarounds?

I am puzzled, since they explicitly state:

> Testcontainers requires a Docker-API compatible container runtime. During development, Testcontainers is actively tested against recent versions of Docker on Linux, as well as against **Docker Desktop on Mac** and Windows. **These Docker environments are automatically detected and used by Testcontainers without any additional configuration being necessary.**

---

`program.cs`:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Builders;

// Create a new instance of a container.
var container = new ContainerBuilder()
  // Set the image for the container to "testcontainers/helloworld:1.1.0".
  .WithImage("testcontainers/helloworld:1.1.0")
  // Bind port 8080 of the container to a random port on the host.
  .WithPortBinding(8080, true)
  // Build the container configuration.
  .Build();

// Start the container.
await container.StartAsync()
  .ConfigureAwait(false);

// ... remaining code omitted
```

Comment: Can you please try one of the mentioned workarounds from [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/issues/890)? A fix will be available with version 3.3.0.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! I wonder how I didn't find that with google.

Comment:  I will pin the issue again until the fix is shipped.